# How do I fix IntelliJ IDEA Error Library 'Maven x has broken javadoc/source path?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have around 30 errors in my project structure window of IntelliJ. I am using maven to build my project and manage dependencies. Some of the dependencies have one of/both of the following errors:

```
Library 'Maven x' has broken javadoc path: <path to local repo>
Library 'Maven x' has broken source path: <path to local repo>
```

For instance I get both of these errors for commons-logging:commons-logging-api:1.1

I've tried running the following commands, but I still have errors:

```
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=sources
```

Are these errors a result of the library not publishing its source and javadocs to the maven repo? Is there a way to get these errors to go away without manually installing the dependency into my local repo (I imaging this would become a maintenance issue ever time I update a library)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are these errors a result of the library not publishing its source and javadocs to the maven repo?

Yes, it's most likely the case.

> Is there a way to get these errors to go away without manually installing the dependency into my local repo

Global errors component at the bottom of the **Project Structure** dialog should no longer display such errors starting from IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.1, however they are still displayed in the library tool-tips.

There is an [open request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-46093) to not add links to the roots that do not exist when performing Maven import, please watch/vote.

Comment: Well, this happens randomly after the Scala plugin upgrade too. This is neither the fix nor the exhaustive answer to this question.